# Ubuntu 18.04 wifi 'Authentication required by wireless network' following software update

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

Immediately following a recent software update I'm no longer able to connect to wifi. Connection attempts receive the message 'Authentication required by wireless network'. The authentication details are correctly entered.

The problem is with any wifi connection. Other devices connect to the same wifi connections.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.5 on a Dell XPS13. The wifi drivers are 'backport-iwlwifi'. I've tried reinstalling these.

I've looked at other questions but don't find an answer that works.

Comment: Try restarting network manager using `systemctl`. If messing with this doesn't work, maybe try reinstalling it and rebooting? Not sure if this is actually the issue at hand here. If you can, please also upload the logs here relevant to the WiFi issue, it may contain an error code (hopefully!) or some kind of verbose reporting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling the iwlwifi driver backport in the Additional Drivers tab of the Software Updater settings fixes the problem.

The iwlwifi driver was installed because previous Ubuntu drivers did not work with the XPS13 wifi card. Presumably the software update fixed this but caused a conflict with the iwlwifi driver.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with connecting to eduroam. The way I fixed it was by typing in my full university email address in username.